# anyone have examples of sophisticated WORD 2007 forms that posts to access DB?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-word

anyone have examples of sophisticated WORD 2007 forms that posts to access DB using ADODB connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will this combination of links help?

- [Please Fill Out This Form, Part 5](http://www.computorcompanion.com/LPMArticle.asp?ID=136)
- [Word Automated forms / VBA](http://www.mousetrax.com/techpage.html#autoforms)

Comment: thank you! do u know the answer to this?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3321635/how-do-i-suppress-do-you-want-to-insert-this-record-on-submit