# how do i suppress: "do you want to insert this record" on SUBMIT?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-word

i am filling out a form on a word document which posts to access database,.

does anyone know if there a way to suppress the message `"do you want to insert this record"???`

raj mentioned that this is possible to do manually, uncheck ACTION QUERIES, but can i do this programmatically/????

Comment: Yes, but I think you need to make a call to a function that has upper-case letters in it, so you're probably out of luck... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given [your other question...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3321449/adodb-connection-to-accdb-file)

Remove the line from your code.

Comment: This one `bytContinue = MsgBox("Do you want to insert this record?", vbYesNo, "Add Record")`. But you'll have to rewrite it instead of removing it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to fix it

Run MS Access open a database.  In the menu, under Tools / Options, uncheck the check-box for **ACTION QUERIES**.

This is machine specific (not database specific).

This is possible through VBA but only for the current running instance. You can do `DoCmd.SetWarnings FALSE`

---

LOL...

In your "other question" referred to, you are asking this question in code

`bytContinue = MsgBox("Do you want to insert this record?", vbYesNo, "Add Record")`

Just replace that line with

`bytContinue = vbYes`

Comment: is it possible to programmatically do this>?